# How to set EdgeWeights in SpatialGraphDistribution?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have a table of random geometric graphs

```
graphs = Table[
   RandomGraph[
    SpatialGraphDistribution[
     RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[100]], 0.2]], {k, 1, 
    10}];
```

but I need the `EdgeWeights` of each graph to be the Euclidean distances between the vertices of the respective edge. At the moment they are all unity.

I tried using

```
graphs = SetProperty[#, 
     EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ EdgeList[#]] & /@ graphs;
```

but this obviously requires the vertex names to be position vectors. I also tried using

```
vertlist[graph_] := 
 VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexCoordinates]
```

with another function which threads over the edges, but it seems inelegant...

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Can you just set the `VertexNames` as `VertexCoordinates` via `SetProperty`, then again use `SetProperty[#, 
     EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ EdgeList[#]] & /@ graphs`?

Comment: If you want to replace the vertex names with the vertex coordinates, you could use `VertexReplace[rg, Thread[VertexList[rg] -> GraphEmbedding[rg]]]`

Comment: I'm thinking about what would be a good general way to deal with similar problems.  I could extend IGraph/M with a new property operator `IGEdgeVertexProp` (not sure what's a good name...) which could be used as `IGEdgeMap[Apply[EuclideanDistance], 
 EdgeWeight -> IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexCoordinates], rg]`. I'm not 100% happy with this though ...  Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
rg = RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[100]], 0.2]]

dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ 
   Map[PropertyValue[{rg, #}, VertexCoordinates] &, EdgeList[rg], {2}];

SetProperty[
 rg,
 EdgeWeight -> dist
]
```

---

An alternative solution is

```
Graph[rg, 
 EdgeWeight -> {edge_ :> Apply[EuclideanDistance]@Map[PropertyValue[{rg, #}, VertexCoordinates] &]@edge}
]
```

What seems to be unavoidable is to first create the graph *and assign it to a variable*, then refer back to that variable.  This is a general "problem" with the current design of the graph framework. It's a problem in the sense that doing this feels un-Mathematica-like.

Comment: Thank you, that should be fine.